# Accessing Supermicro IPMI via SSH

Tags: ipmi, supermicro, bmc

When you deal with Supermicro IPMI/BMC, you could access it via:

- HTTP(S) in your browser - seeing web pages with sensors/configs and java applet to run redirection console
- IPMI protocol (using `ipmitool`-like CLI or `IPMIView`-like GUI apps)

Once I discovered I could just `ssh ADMIN@my.ipmi.address.net` and get into the BMC - there is Linux-like shell, `ifconfig` (not with server's, but with BMC's network settings), and - the greatest thing! - ability to tape `reboot` to reset BMC when IPMI starts glitching.

But now, having access to numerous Supermicro boxes with IPMI, I discover that SSH access works differently: about a half of boxes runs "normal" shell on IPMI's 22 port, other runs the "ATEN SMASH-CLP System Management Shell". It is not Linux-like, not supports standard commands like `ls`, and I can't reset BMC with it.

Google mainly says of SMASH-CLP in source-of-security-breaches way. Is there any user documentation for it? Or could I make my IPMI/BMC run "normal" shell via SSH, not SMASH-CLP?

I deal with X9DRW-iF, X9DRi-F and X9SCL-F motherboards.

Comment: Tried reading the documentation of them?

Comment: Supermicro gives only motherboard manuals: [X9DRW](http://www.supermicro.nl/products/motherboard/xeon/c600/x9drw-if.cfm), [X9DRi](http://www.supermicro.nl/products/motherboard/xeon/c600/x9dri-f.cfm), [X9SCL](http://www.supermicro.nl/products/motherboard/xeon/c202_c204/x9scl-f.cfm) - and there are no SSH/SMASH mentions on it.

I guess BCM vendor is not connected to motherboard vendor, Supermicro just built 3rd-party hardware (BMC) and firmware for it into their motherboards.

Comment: 4 different IPMI user guides are found on the [main Supermicro documentation](http://www.supermicro.nl/support/manuals/) page including the [SMT IPMI Manual](http://www.supermicro.nl/manuals/other/SMT_IPMI_Manual.pdf) which includes SMASH in appendix B.

Comment: Note that you can reboot the BMC remotely using `$ ipmitool -H 1.2.3.4 -U ADMIN -E -I lanplus bmc reset warm` (or `cold`). I haven't found the SMASH-CLP useful at all. Supermicro provides different BMCs from different vendors, each with a different implementation of a CLP, learning what is possible is a serious pain and doesn't apply to all nodes.

Answer (score 3):

Say I wish to use server A to reach the IPMI interface of server B, then this works for me:

```
ipmitool -H 10.0.0.2 -U user -Ppassword chassis power cycle
```

Answer (score 2):

On all my Super Micro BMCs there is a hidden SMASH command to drop out of the default environment and into a BusyBox shell.

Try typing "shell sh" in the SMASH shell and see if that works.

Comment: This doesn't work on all of my Supermicro boxes, sadly. It is even inconsistant in X9 mobos as well.

Comment: This "hidden command" was considered as bug and was removed in new BMC firmwares.

Comment: [some context](https://blog.rapid7.com/2013/11/15/exploiting-the-supermicro-onboard-ipmi-controller/) to why it was removed - with 2017 produced Supermicro boards a `shell sh` yields 'shell command not support now.'.